# Method returning 0

Tags: objective-c, calculator

I'm doing the foundation calculator homework from the cs193p course, and my
`+evaluateExpression:usingVariables:` method doesn't work. It always returns 0.

Here's my method:

```
+ (double)evaluateExpression: (id)anExpression usingVariablevalues: (NSDictionary *)variables {
CalculatorBrain *worker = [[[CalculatorBrain alloc] init] autorelease];
double returnValue = 10.0;
if ([anExpression isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    for (id term in anExpression) {
        NSLog(@"%f", returnValue);         // breakpoint
        if ([term isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {                                    // string
            if ([term hasPrefix:@"%"] && [term length] == 2) {                          // variable
                double value = [(NSNumber *)[variables objectForKey:[term substringFromIndex:1]] doubleValue];
                NSLog(@"Variable: %@, value: %d", [term substringFromIndex:1], value);
                [worker setOperand:value];
            }
            else if ([term length] == 1) {                                              // operation
                returnValue = [worker performOperation:term];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Invalid expression.\n\tMultiple character operation found: %@", term);
            }
        }
        else if ([term isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {                                   // operand
            double value = [term doubleValue];
            [worker setOperand:value];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid expression.\n\tWrong type in expression: %@, The value is: %@.",[term class], term);    // Wrong type in expression
        }

    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid expression.\n\tThe expression is of the wrong type: %@.", [anExpression class]);    // expression is of wrong type
}
//returnValue = worker.operand;
return returnValue;
}
```

Any hints? it always returns 0.

```
/* Ouput from Console */
2012-06-27 20:01:05.487 Calculator[2823:207] 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.488 Calculator[2823:207] 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.489 Calculator[2823:207] 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.490 Calculator[2823:207] Variable: x, value: 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.490 Calculator[2823:207] 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.491 Calculator[2823:207] 0
2012-06-27 20:01:05.491 Calculator[2823:207] 0
```

Note: I set returnValue to 10.0 at the beginning to check if it is getting changed at all.

**Update:**

I found out that it gets 0 from the dictionary. I think the calling code is the cause:

```
- (IBAction) performSampleExpression {
    NSMutableArray *expr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    [expr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.0]];
    [expr addObject:@"+"];
    [expr addObject:@"%x"];
    [expr addObject:@"*"];
    [expr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.0]];

    NSDictionary *varsdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:10.0], @"x", nil];

    double result = [CalculatorBrain evaluateExpression:expr usingVariablevalues:varsdict];
    if (!result) NSLog(@"result = nil");
    NSLog(@"%f", result);

    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
    [expr release];
}
```

Result isn't nil though.

**Update 2:**

Using the debugger (nice hint. This might solve it.) I found something strange:

On this line: (first time)

```
returnValue = worker.operand;
```

It says returnValue is still 10, and not three (worker.operand IS).
Is the assignment failing, or is this how it should be? (Just wondering).

**UPDATE 3:**

Okay there is something very strange going on here: I set a breakpoint on the return statement, the last line of `+evaluateExpression:usingVariables:`, and it says
`returnValue = 4`.
This means, the actual problem lies in `-performSampleExpression`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 4:**

Changing `@"%d", double` into `@"%f", double` helped a lot. That explains the strange Console output. But, it solved it, because I updated the display like display `[setText:@"%d", result];` what caused my double to be displayed as 0 due to a wrong cast.
I discovered this by using the debugger, so the one who suggested that practically solved it. (And I asked for `hints`, not for solutions. After all, homework is to learn from).

Comment: What should your input look like?

Comment: @trojanfoe no, calculatorbrain is working fine. Then it must be in how I am using it. But I couldn't find something like that.

Comment: @hamstergene how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible issues can shown in:

```
 returnValue = [worker performOperation:term];
```

and

```
returnValue = worker.operand;
```

You should stop debugger in this line (or line below) and watch how to your value of `returnValue` change.

[image: Screen]

You stop app clicking on position where it is on the screen, app stops, and then jump to next line with F6 (or Fn+F6). Below (in console) you can see the value.

**EDIT**

You could try this solution - Change allocation to:

```
CalculatorBrain *worker = [[[CalculatorBrain alloc] init] autorelease];
```

And delete line:

```
 [worker release];
```

This release right before return may couse the problem without NSCopying @protocol.

**Autorelease and NSCopying**

For better understanding compile this code:

```
NSMutableArray *arrOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrTwo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

arrTwo = arrOne;
[arrOne addObject:@"3"]; //After that arrTwo "shold" be 1,2 and arrOne 1,2,3. No! There both 1,2,3!

for(int i=0;i<[arrTwo count];i++)
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrTwo objectAtIndex:i]);
```

So you may consider how you assign a variable. In above example releasing memory shouldn't effect return values, but by using autorelease with return object you don't have to assign anything.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using debugger! Changing the memory management didn't help though. Because 2 people suggested this, could you explain why? I don't wuite understand it.

Comment: autorelease release memory when object is no longer necessary. For example when you leave a loop, method or something like that, depends on implementation. If you want to release something right after return you have a problem. Couse `Foo *bar = [[Foo alloc] init];` initialize an object, but what if you have in method: `Foo *bar = [[Foo alloc] init]; return bar`. This is a leak!! But if you declare it like `Foo *bar = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease]; return bar` memory will be release right after return, so you get your value and ther is *no memory leak!* Cheers!

Comment: I had no leak... Perhaps a typo in the question.

Comment: no, I had no leak. I released it right before the return statement.

Comment: No, no i don't say you do in your code, I mean that if you alloc like above example. assign a pointer is *NOT* like c++ pointer assign. I;m now editing my answer, there code will look better

Comment: So... If I autorelease it, and then once assign it to a `double *` it keeps getting updated? Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stepping through the code a line at a time and examining the variable values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a little memory leak in your code:

so, instead of this:
`[worker release];`

try this line: `[worker autorelease];`

I'm not sure it caused the problem but your version definitely does not look good.

Comment: Why? I don't quite understand. I *should* release it, don't I?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that returnValue could be a pointer to, but it was a `double` and not a `double *`.